# cardinality of possibilities for distribution $10$ children to $6$ chairs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

`**Question:** How to get the cardinality to distribute  $10$ chilrdren to $6$ chairs in a circle

If I have to distribute $10$ chilrdren to $6$ chairs in a circle, the order will not matter and each child cannot be rechosen.

So I have calculated: $|Perm_6(10)|= \frac{10!}{(10-6)!}= 151 200$

However the correct solution is 25200. So $\frac{151200}{6}=25200$

Why do I have to devide it by $6$?

Comment: Well, it's a circle so $ABCDEF$ is the same as $FABCDE$ and so on.

Comment: Did you mean to say that the correct solution is $\frac{151200}{6}$?

Comment: @lulu: my problem is to understand why I have not to use the binomial coefficient $\binom{10}{6}$ here. I see the solution is different but I do not see the logic behind there. I have learnt that we can use a binomial coefficient if no element can be rechosen and the order does not matter. On the other hand the permutation is used if no element can be rechosen but the order does matter.

Comment: Parts of the order matter...$ABCDEF$ is not the same as $BACDEF$.  Note that $F$ has different neighbors.  So you are correct to use permutations, but then you need to divide by $6$ to kill the cyclic symmetry.

Comment: In any "arrangement" question you have to ask "which arrangements do we say are equivalent"?  If you are putting your kids in a line, then your answer is correct.  In a circle, I'd say you should divide by $6$ but a case could be made for dividing by $12$ (if we add reflection symmetry to our sense of equivalence).  If we reflect then everybody keeps the same neighbors!  But $A's$ left neighbor is now her right neighbor and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider three persons A,B,C in two chairs in a row

possible arrangements are

> AB
>  BA
>  AC
>  CA 
> BC
>  CA

This is what we get by $\dfrac{3!}{(3-2)!}=6$

When we consider a circle, AB and BA are same, because one can be transformed to the other by rotating. Similarly, AC and CA are same, BC and CB are same. So, we ends up with $3$ arrangements only.

To get this, we have to divide by $2$

i.e., $\dfrac{3!}{(3-2)!2}=3$

Comment: So you mean divide it by 6!

Comment: sorry, typo. corrected.